# WebAudio AAC streaming playback from WebSocket

Tags: websocket, web-audio-api

I need to playback aac (adts) streaming from WebSocket, I searched the internet and found aac.js can do it but sounds like delay almost 2~5 seconds.

And I found some people use WebAudio stuff to do it. I try it with below code but decoder return error after some packets (not always but repeat error):

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to decode audio data
```

My sample javascript:

```
  var context  = new AudioContext();
  var nextStartTime = 0;

  var audioWs = new WebSocket("ws://" + hostip + ":8084");
  audioWs.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';

  audioWs.onopen = function(evt) {
      console.log("onOpen");
      bexit = 0;
  };

  audioWs.onclose = function(evt) {
      console.log("close");
  };

  audioWs.onmessage = function(evt) {
      var blob = evt.data;
      if ( blob.slice == undefined) {
          console.log("undefined message");
          return;
      }
      decodeAudio(blob);
  };

  audioWs.onerror = function(evt) {
      console.log("error");
  };

  var decodeAudio = function(blob) {
      context.decodeAudioData(
          blob,
          function(buffer) {
              if (!buffer) {
                  console.log('error decoding file data: ' + url);
                  return;
              }
              console.log("playback buffer");
              playBuffer(buffer);
          },
          function(error) {
              console.error("decodeAudioData error", error);
          });
  };

  var playBuffer = function(buffer) {
      var source = context.createBufferSource();
      source.buffer = buffer;
      if(nextStartTime == 0){
          nextStartTime = context.currentTime + buffer.duration/2;
      }
      source.connect(context.destination);
      source.start(nextStartTime);
      nextStartTime += buffer.duration;
  };
```

I not sure if it's caused by data received from websocket incomming too fast then cause decoder error! How should I fix it?

Or maybe it's not good way to do this task with WebAudio API?

Comment: Try Media Source Extension for streaming playback.

Answer (score 1):

WebAudio's `decodeAudioData` can't decode partial blobs.  It needs the whole file, in general, because in many encoded formats, the necessary information (sample rates, channels, sample size, etc.) is only at the beginning.